# Gave up waiting for root file system device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I run a dual boot ubuntu20 & windows10. When I select ubuntu on GRUB it prompt me to :

"
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls/dev)

Alert! UUID=........ does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
"

I'm stuck, and need my ubuntu session ASAP.
WOULD BE APPRECIATED IF ANYONE CAN HELP.

Comment: Where's the picture?

Comment: @Liso Couldn't upload it. I typed the message.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Liso Yes, thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a UEFI mode system, a UUID is used in two places in the boot process.  The first  in the three line stub (/boot/efi)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg -- if you see the full grub menu, that UUID successfully identified the root filesystem, to find the full /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.  The second place is in the actual grub boot instructions on the line starting with "linux".  Type "E" to see the actual grub instructions and compare that UUID to the one from the stub grub.cfg, they should be the same.  If not, edit the UUID (instructions at the bottom of teh grub screen). and then run update-grub after the first successful boot.